# Visualizing the Fourier and Laplace transform

Tags: fourier-series, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I know that
$$F(\omega):=\mathscr{F}\{f(t)\}(\omega)=\int\limits_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$L(s):=\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}(s)=\int\limits_{t=0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$$
But what's the 'visual' connection between the function $f(t)$ and it's Laplace transform $L(t)$ and $f(t)$ and it's Fourier transform $F(t)$? Like in the case of Fourier series; it represents the function as a linear combination of sinusoids.

Comment: Thanks @reuns. It was misunderstandable; I'm not looking for the connection between the 2 transformations, but between the function and it's transformation.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}[f(t)](\sigma+i\omega) = \mathcal{F}[f(t)e^{-\sigma t} 1_{t > 0}](\omega)$. The inverse Fourier transform doesn't represent $f$ as a sum of sinusoids, but as an integral, which is quite different : $f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i n t/ N} f_{[\frac{n}{N},\frac{n+1}{N}]}(t)$ where $f_{[\frac{n}{N},\frac{n+1}{N}]}(t) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{1/N} \hat{f}(\frac{n}{N}+\omega) e^{i \omega t}dt$, thus $f$ becomes a sum of **band-limited** signals (ie. that look like a sinsuoid, locally, but allowed to vary slowly in time)

Comment: @reuns I still don't get it.

Comment: What ? Do you see how the series I wrote is some sort of time-varying Fourier series ? When $N \to \infty$ it is the Fourier transform integral.

Comment: @reuns Well, I don't really get the reason for including the inverse transform here. I would like to know the connection between the $e^{at} u(t)$ and it's laplace transform $\frac{1}{s-a}$, and the same goes for it's fourier transform $\frac{1}{i \omega - a}$; because they are not so similar functions.

Comment: What is not similar ? With the Fourier series you get $g(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_n c_n e^{in t}$, with the Fourier transform it is $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega) e^{i \omega t}d\omega$. Both deserve to be called Fourier inversion theorems.

Comment: The $e^{something}$ and the $\frac{1}{something}$. For example, this is the $e^{2t}$, and it's laplace transform: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BHewxSu20_VpgR2AQYOaf8Vov9tBkxt8 (It was easier to plot the laplace in R to R than the fourier in R to C); they look totally different. But the fourier series do "keep the shape of the function", for example this one: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Fourier_Series.svg/316px-Fourier_Series.svg.png

Comment: For say $f,f',g,g'$ continuous and integrable and $g$ $\ 2\pi$-periodic, $\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t}dt$, $c_n = \int_0^{2\pi} g(t) e^{-int}dt$. Then $\hat{f}$ doesn't look like $f$, in the same way that $c_n$ doesn't look like $g$. The point is the convergence/inversion theorem : $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega) e^{i \omega t}d\omega$, $g(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_n c_n e^{in t}$, and the fact everything behaves nicely under differentiation, integration, shift, convolution.

Comment: @reuns the f' and g' are supposed to be f hat and g hat?